# Magento 2: How to get the full size of the page?

Tags: magento2, css

I need to get the size of the whole page to gain space, I've tried it with **CSS** but there's no way.

As I show in the image I would like to get the empty space that remains on the side edges.

[image]

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `.page-main` to have a max-width of `100%`. I can't give you the exact code as I know nothing about your workflow but changing or adding the following should work.

```
.page-main {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Or if you want this change to apply site-wide change the `@layout__max-width` variable to be `100%` in `lib/web/css/source/lib/variables/_layout.less:12`.